# Incrementing a variable value inside a pod when scaling up (for the scaled pod)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod/deployment initially with one replica. **The code in the pod contains a variable/counter of type int**. Initially equals  one,  and then when I scale the deployment. I want the second pod replica to set that variable/counter to two only in the second replica (while the value remains one in the first), and similarly when I scale to three replicas {replica1:counter=1, replica2:counter=2, replica3:counter=3) etc...

Can you please suggest a simple way to achieve the above if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stateful sets if no issue with it, as it manages the sequence so.

You can use the name of POD as an environment so this, as stateful set will scale up it, will have a name as a variable for **int** you might need to parse or slice it as per need.

```
env:
  - name: MY_POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
  - name: env0
    value: value
```

Readmore at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/